# Motherboard Monitor no image

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

First time posting here.

I am running 14.04, and have been using it with my monitor plugged into my nvidia graphics card (GeForce GT 610).

I recently obtained a new monitor, and tried to plug it into the motherboard VGA slot, but no image appears on the second monitor.

If I only plug into the motherboard, no displays work. So basically - can someone explain how to connect the second monitor to the motherboard VGA?

The motherboard is a MSI Z-97 PC Mate.

Below are the outputs from xrandr and lspci:

Thanks in advance!

```
$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cb1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cba
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cad
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 8ca0
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8c90 (rev d0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8c98 (rev d0)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8c9a (rev d0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d0)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8ca6
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8cc4
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 8c82
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 8ca2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0 +
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
   1280x1024_60.00   59.9
```

Comment: Turns out I had to go through my motherboard BIOS and turn on its onboard graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't a problem with Ubuntu. I'm pretty sure it's a setting in your BIOS setup. Hold down the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key when you turn on the computer to enter the BIOS setup. Somewhere inside there should be an option for the internal graphics card (whether to have it enabled or disabled). You'll need to set this to be enabled, then hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to save the changes and restart. If there is no such option, the decision is made automatically, and you can't control it. A lot of motherboards will disable the internal graphics when a PCI card is plugged in, without you having the option to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes unplugging the graphics card, rebooting, then plugging the card in again will force the internal graphics card in the motherboard to stay on.